# Random string from list of strings

Tags: c#, random

I want to generate a string from a list of strings. I did this but it only shows the number of the arrays:

```
Random r1 = new Random();
string[] fruits = new string[7];
fruits[0] = "cherry";
fruits[1] = "blueberry";
fruits[2] = "banana";
fruits[3] = "melon";
fruits[4] = "apple";
fruits[5] = "pear";
fruits[6] = "watermelon";

Console.WriteLine(r1.Next(fruits.Length));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Console.WriteLine(fruits[r1.Next(fruits.Length)]);
```

E.g. Fruits[2] is the 3th in array, because it starts at 0